# WebDriverException when Background

Tags: android, python, selenium, webdriver, appium

We have a recurring error testing Android. When I do `self.driver.background_app(3)` sometimes we receive a `WebDriverException`.

We have to do background to update the XML tree of uiAutomator. If we don't do that, I can't wait for any element there because they never appear.

My questions are the following:

1. Can we do another thing to refresh the XML tree?
2. What can we do to avoid `WebDriverExceptions`?

Here i add some code where this happens:

```
def click_byId(id):
    global driver, var_debug

    if var_debug:
        print("    DEBUG: Clicking button by id: '%s'" % id)

    element = driver.find_element_by_id(id)
    element.click()
```

.
.
.

```
click_byId("Entrar")
self.driver.background_app(3)
click_byId("Inicio")
```

the problem is that this happens from time to time, with the same mobile phone and the same script.

In appium we can read something like this:

[ADB] Running 'C:/../platform-tools/adb.exe' with args: ["-p",5037,"-s","LGM250LJEE65QCLVHQ","shell","dumpsys","window","windows"]
[ADB] Found package: 'com.app.miapp' and fully qualified activity name: 'com.app.miapp.MainActivity'
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.background() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/542532453-ecde-43a9-7a8788d171b/appium/app/background 200 7408 ms - 76
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/542532453-ecde-43a9-7a8788d171b/element {"using":"id","sessionId":"542532453-ecde-43a9-7a8788d171b","value":"Inicio"}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["id","Inicio","542532453-ecde-43a9-7a8788d171b"]

Then, the execution is blocked and stop running. Later, all finish and we receive by console:

('Unexpected error:', class 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException')

We experience different behaviors changing the time of background. Sometimes when we define the time of background to 1 the exception disappear.

The real question is: Is there any other way to refresh the app's elements in selenium? or appium?

Thanks for the help and sorry for my inexperience.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Please provide an example code.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?